# Array and Object Manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, nested

So I was practicing some JS and this is what I came across nested Objects in arrays.
how can I change the value of of age of every element. I want to change the structure of save these values in a new object with quantity, size, product._id, product.variant._id [my original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ciTP.jpg)

the changes I am hoping [the changes I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLA8W.jpg) I'm able to do this so far but not immutably

```
[
  {
    "quantity": 4,
    "size": "S",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecb",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecc",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 4
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecd",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 13
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: "how can I change the value of of age of every element" - typo? there's no "age" element. And clarify what you mean by "immutably" in "I'm able to do this so far but not immutably".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the map() method in JavaScript which creates an array by calling a specific function on each element present in the parent array

```
const arr =  [
  {
    "quantity": 4,
    "size": "S",
    "product": {
      "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ebe",
      "title": "LEVI Denim",
      "name": "TRUCKER JACKET",
      "category": "men",
      "price": 8999,
      "rating": 5,
      "sales": 69,
      "variant": {
        "img": [
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-front-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1250&hei=1667",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-back-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400",
          "https://lsco.scene7.com/is/image/lsco/levis/clothing/723340131-alt1-pdp.jpg?fmt=jpeg&qlt=70,1&op_sharpen=0&resMode=sharp2&op_usm=0.8,1,10,0&fit=crop,0&wid=1050&hei=1400"
        ],
        "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecb",
        "variantAvailability": true,
        "size": [
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecc",
            "symbol": "S",
            "stock": 4
          },
          {
            "_id": "607283d971fbe12de4e42ecd",
            "symbol": "L",
            "stock": 13
          }
        ]
      },
      "__v": 0
    }
  }
]; 
let tempArr = arr.map(element=>{
    element['productId'] = element.product._id;
    element['variantId'] = element.product.variant._id;
    delete element['product'];
    return element;
  });
```

Comment: You should add some explanation about your code and why it tackles what the OP/s issue is.